Commutators in $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$
Let $SL'(2,\mathbb{Z})$ be the commutator subgroup of $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$, that is, $SL'(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is the group generated by elements of the form
$$ \{ ABA^{-1}B^{-1} : A, B \in \text{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z}) \}. $$
I am trying to understand if every element of $SL'(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is a commutator (and not only a product of commutators and their inverses). I suspect that the answer is "no", and the reason is that $SL'(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is a free group of rank 2, and if every element of $SL'(2,\mathbb{Z})$ was a commutator, it could have meant that there are non-trivial relations in it.
I was wondering if my line of thought makes sense, and if there is any proof that doesn't rely on $SL'(2,\mathbb{Z})$ being free.

It is a general fact about nonelementary hyperbolic groups that there are elements of the commutator subgroup whose commutator length is arbitrarily large. https://www.ams.org/notices/200809/tx080901100p.pdf

Thanks! reading this paper, I see that the stable commutator length of $\text{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is 0 for $n \geq 3$. So it seems in the "other direction" (that is, elements have "short commutator length")

You did not read far enough: You have read the first list, with $scl=0$, but not the following list, with $scl>0$.

Let $G$ be a group and let $G'=[G,G]$ be its derived subgroup. For elements $g\in G'$ one defines its commutator length $cl(g)$ as the smallest number $N$ such that $g$ is the product of $N$ commutators of elements of $G$. One also defines the stable commutator length of $g\in G'$ as
$$
scl(g):= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{cl(g^n)}{n}
$$
(the limit always exists). Thus, if there exists an element $g\in G'$ with $scl(g)>0$, then $G'$ contains elements of arbitrarily high commutator length. In particular, not every element of $G'$ is a commutator. It is a general fact (going back to the work of Epstein and Fujiwara, which, in turn, generalizes an earlier construction of Brooks) that for every nonelementary hyperbolic group $G$ there are elements $g\in G'$ such that $scl(g)>0$. The group $G=SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ contains a free subgroup of rank $\ge 2$ as a finite index subgroup;  hence, $G$ is a nonelementary hyperbolic group. From this, it follows that $G'$ contains elements which are not commutators.
Regrading your attempted argument, it does not work. If you want to see why, you should try to write more details.
For further reading, see
Calegari, Danny, What is ...  stable commutator length?, Notices Am. Math. Soc. 55, No. 9, 1100-1101 (2008). ZBL1152.57303.
Calegari, Danny; Fujiwara, Koji, Stable commutator length in word-hyperbolic groups., Groups Geom. Dyn. 4, No. 1, 59-90 (2010). ZBL1227.20040.
